# Understanding Polymer events and data-bindings with nested elements?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I have three nested polymer elements. Each of them has default values, which may be overridden with published value.

But i can't do it.

On `create` event does not exist published value. On `ready` event child element has already `ready` and not updated.

[I made example js-bin.](http://jsbin.com/ronar/1/edit?html,console,output)

In reality, each element in the separate file. It is example.

Object.assign - es6 method for merging objects (use es6-shim).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.18.0/es6-shim.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/platform/platform.js"></script>
  <link href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import"> 
</head>
<body unresolved>

  <polymer-element name="my-field" attributes="ask">
  <template>
    <span><content></content> Message: {{message}}</span>
  </template>
  <script>
    (function() {
      Polymer('my-field', {
        defaultAsk: { message: "Hello from Field!" },
        created: function() {
          console.log('created-field', this.ask, this.message);  
          Object.assign(this, this.defaultAsk);
        },
        ready: function() {
          console.log('ready-field', this.ask, this.message);
          Object.assign(this, this.ask);
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
  </polymer-element>

  <polymer-element name="my-shelf" attributes="ask">
  <template>
    <my-field ask="{{field}}"><content></content></my-field>
  </template>
  <script>
    (function() {
      Polymer('my-shelf', {
        defaultAsk: { field: { message: "Hello from Shelf!" } },
        created: function() {
          console.log('created-shelf', this.ask, this.field);  
          Object.assign(this, this.defaultAsk);
        },
        ready: function() {
          console.log('ready-shelf', this.ask, this.field);
          Object.assign(this, this.ask);
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
  </polymer-element>

  <polymer-element name="my-cabinet">
  <template>
    <my-shelf ask="{{shelf}}"><content></content></my-shelf>        
  </template>   
  <script>
    (function() {
      Polymer('my-cabinet', {
        ask:        { shelf: { field: { message: "Hello from outside!" } } },
        defaultAsk: { shelf: { field: { message: "Hello from Cabinet!" } } },
        created: function() {
          console.log('created-cabinet', this.ask, this.shelf);  
          Object.assign(this, this.defaultAsk);
        },
        ready: function() {
          console.log('ready-cabinet', this.ask, this.shelf);
          Object.assign(this, this.ask);
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
  </polymer-element>

  <my-cabinet>Yo!</my-cabinet>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

All will working as I want, if use only **one object** through many nested elements.

[Example on js-bin](http://jsbin.com/xorose/1/edit?html,js,output)

All my element extended of other one (my-elem) only for remove doubled code and make my example more readable. `ask` - binding data (from my-cabinet to my-field). `Click` - changing data.

Unfortunately, on jsbin wery uneasy console for view fired messages.

I made small schema of chain events with nested elements. Maybe, it will help someone.

[image]

p.s. Don't kick me for my bad english.